# Range Column and add Value to the specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel file that I want to filter about one column and on another column add specific value

[image: The Excel file]

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1
'

'
    Range("Table1[type phone]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*samsung*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("Table1[company]").Select

        'Here I want to  add the specific value "Samsung"'

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*iphone*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("Table1[company]").Select

        'Here I want to  add the specific value "Apple"'

End Sub
```

Also how can I filter about one column Blanks cells and on another column add specific value "other"?

[[image: others Items[2]]

What conditions can be written if, for example, the Samsung Devices table is missing?
Because if I run the code it crashes in the line it is looking for Samsung.

[image: Without Samsung Devices]

How can I do it? 
Thank You for helping!

Comment: If you want to apply the filter using VBA you might remove the existing filter, based on one column, and apply a new filter based on two columns.

Comment: How can I do it? Variatus

Comment: You might record a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of only cells that are visible (aka those that are show in the filter) you can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

So for your example the code that would go in the first break would be

`"Range("B2:B18").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value= "Samsung"`

and the second break

`"Range("B2:B18").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value= "Apple"`

You need to change "18" to whatever the last row is. (Or you can define a variable called LastRow and then call that instead of hard-coding the number which means it will dynamically change based on how many rows there are.)

---

With LastRow

```
Sub Macro1()

 Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("Table1[type phone]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*samsung*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("Table1[company]").Select

Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value= "Samsung"

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*iphone*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("Table1[company]").Select

Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value= "Apple"
End Sub
```

We created a new variable called LastRow and defined it as long (A type of number). Then we defined LastRow according to a formula I use from this site: 
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Finally we replace Range("B2:B18") with Range("B2:B" & LastRow) which dynamically replaces the 18 with the number LastRow.

Comment: Thank you it is working but How can I get the last row with a variable?

Comment: @EranPeer I edited my post with the full code as well as a brief explanation. Feel free to ask further questions as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much but you can help me please to filter with blank cells to write "other" ?

Comment: @EranPeer I think you should be able to figure out how to do that by repeating the processes you already know. Try it first. If you cannot figure it out post the code you are using and I will help.

Comment: I got along but there is another problem unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm sorry I'm digging.
What conditions can be written if, for example, the Samsung Devices table is missing? Because if I run the code it crashes in the line it is looking for Samsung.

Comment: What you want in that case is an `IF THEN` statement. You'll want it to be `IF samsung is in the list THEN samsung code ENDIF` If you needed to figure out if some text was in a large column of text (without filters) what would you do? Once you know what it is Google it with "Excel VBA + thing" and see if you can get it working. ((Also trying to help you learn how to do the code instead of writing it for you. Sorry if that is frustrating at all.))